# How do I combine three observables such that

Tags: system.reactive

If I have three observables, how do I combine them such that when the first emit a new value, I can combine that with the latest emitted from the other two.. Its important that we only produce a new value of the combined observables when the first observable has a new value regardles of whether the other two has emitted new values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this (note that you get default values for sources 2 and 3 if they have yet to emit, and I have allowed for you to optionally supply those default values):

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TResult> CombineFirstWithLatestOfRest
        <TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TResult>(
        this IObservable<TSource1> source1,
        IObservable<TSource2> source2,
        IObservable<TSource3> source3,
        Func<TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TResult> resultSelector,
        TSource2 source2Default = default(TSource2),
        TSource3 source3Default = default(TSource3))
    {
        var latestOfRest = source2.CombineLatest(source3, Tuple.Create);
        return source1.Zip(latestOfRest.MostRecent(
            Tuple.Create(source2Default, source3Default)),
            (s1,s23) => resultSelector(s1, s23.Item1, s23.Item2));
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
var source1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var source2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var source3 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.5));

var res = source1.CombineFirstWithLatestOfRest(source2, source3,
    (x,y,z) => string.Format("1: {0} 2: {1} 3: {2}", x,y,z));    

res.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

#### Addendum

There's a subtle problem here that might be significant in your scenario. A sometimes undesirable aspect of `CombineLatest` is that it does not emit until it has a value from every contributing stream. This means in the example above that the slower `source3` holds up `source2` and values are missed. Specifically, events returned will have the default values for both `source2` and `source3` until *both* have emitted at least one event each. Kicking off `source2` and `source3` with their default values is a convenient workaround for this behaviour, which we can get away with since it is `source1` that drives events:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TResult> CombineFirstWithLatestOfRest
        <TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TResult>(
        this IObservable<TSource1> source1,
        IObservable<TSource2> source2,
        IObservable<TSource3> source3,
        Func<TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TResult> resultSelector,
        TSource2 source2Default = default(TSource2),
        TSource3 source3Default = default(TSource3))
    {   
        source2 = source2.StartWith(source2Default); // added this
        source3 = source3.StartWith(source3Default); // and this           
        var lastestOfRest = source2.CombineLatest(source3, Tuple.Create);            
        return source1.Zip(lastestOfRest.MostRecent(
            Tuple.Create(source2Default, source3Default)), // now redundant
            (s1,s23) => resultSelector(s1, s23.Item1, s23.Item2));
    }             
}
```

Comment: Great use of the esoteric `MostRecent` operator.